# Change Checkout Billing Address dropdown to list view

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, knockoutjs, billing-address

I want to change billing address drop down in checkout page similar to shipping address view list template.
I have tried the following code in

> app\design\frontend....\Magento_Checkout\web\template\billing-address\list.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<div class="field field-select-billing">
    <label class="label"><span data-bind="i18n: 'Billing Address'"></span></label>
    <div class="control" data-bind="forach: addressOptions">
        <input type="radio" data-bind="attr:{value: 'selectedAddress',id:customerAddressId}"/>
        <label class="label" data-bind="attr:{for:customerAddressId}">
            <span data-bind="text:addressOptionsText"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am getting console error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "attr: function(){return {value:'selectedAddress',id:customerAddressId} }"
Message: customerAddressId is not defined
```

My goal is to achieve the same template as in shipping address in checkout .Please help.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Use `selectedAddress().customerAddressId` to get the id of selected address